# How to "hash" long String into String[64] in Java

Tags: java, mysql, hash

I have a Java application which works with MySQL database.

I want to be able to store long texts and check whether table contains them. For this I want to use index, and search by reduced "hash" of full_text.

```
MY_TABLE [
    full_text: TEXT
    text_hash: varchar(255) - indexed
]
```

Thing is, I cannot use String.hashCode() as:

1. Implementation may vary across JVM versions.
2. Value is too short, which means many collisions.

I want to find a fast hashing function that will read the long text value and produce a long hash value for it, say 64 symbols long.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such reliable hash methods are not fast. They're probably fast enough, though. You're looking for a cryptographic message digest method (like the ones used to identify files in P2P networks or commits in Git). Look for the [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class, and pick your algorithm (SHA1, MD5, SHA256, etc.).

Such a hash function will take bytes as argument, and produce bytes as a result, so make sure to convert your strings using a constant encoding (UTF8, for example), and to transform the produced byte array (typically of 16 or 20 bytes) to a readable String using hexadecimal or Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you to revisit `String.hashCode()`.

First, it does not vary across implementations. The exact hash is specified; see the [String.hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--) javadoc specification.

Second, while the String hash algorithm isn't the best there possibly is (and certainly it will have more collisions than a cryptographic hash) it does do a reasonably good job of spreading the hashes over the 32-bit result space. For example, I did a quick check of a text file on my machine (`/usr/share/dict/web2a`) which has 235,880 words, and there were **six** collisions.

Third and fourth: `String.hashCode()` should be considerably faster, and the storage required for the hash values should be considerably smaller, than a cryptographic hash.

If you're storing strings in a database table, and their hash values are indexed, having a few collisions shouldn't matter. Looking up a string should get you the right database rows really quickly, and having to (maybe) check a couple actual strings should be very fast compared to the database I/O.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using mzHash64, a very simple, fast function with a number of collisions very close to an ideal Universal Hash Function

```
public static long mzHash64(byte[] data, int start, int length, long seed) {    
    long hash = 0xD45E69F901E72147L ^ seed;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        hash = 0x3631754B22FF2D5CL * (i + data[start + i]) ^ (hash << 2) ^ (hash >>> 2);

    return hash;
}

public static long mzHash64(String str) {
    byte[] data = str.getBytes();
    return mzHash64(data, 0, data.length, 0);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/matteo65/mzHash64

32 bit version: https://github.com/matteo65/mzHash32